# trying to create a select2 wrapper

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to create a wrapper around select2 that can either accept a url or an array containing the data.
If I pass data to the wrapper then I want to disable the ajax requests from being triggered after every letter typed in.

How can I configure this behavior if data is passed then disable ajax requests (without having to replicate the code and have an if)

Basically the following code

```
  SelectTwo.init = (el, text, url, data = []) ->
    @_url = url
    @_data = data

    el.select2
      placeholder: text
      minimumInputLength: 2
      data: @_data
      ajax:
        url: (term) =>
          @_url + '/' + term
        dataType: "json"
        results: (data, page) ->
          results: data
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `el.select2` is an object of options, it doesn't have to be an object literal, just an object. That means that you can build the object piece by piece based on the arguments to `init`.

You could do something like this:

```
SelectTwo.init = (el, text, data_source = { }) ->
  select_opts =
    placeholder: text
    minimumInputLength: 2

  if(data_source.url)
    select_opts.ajax =
      url: (term) -> "#{data_source.url}/#{encodeURIComponent(term)}"
      dataType: "json"
      results: (data, page) ->
        results: data
  else if(data_source.data)
    select_opts.data = data_source.data
  else
    # handle this however you want

  el.select2 select_opts
```

Some points of interest:

1. I added an `encodeURIComponent` wrapper around the search term because I'm paranoid and it is a good habit.
2. I switch to string interpolation to build the search URL as that's clearer to me than a bunch of `+`s and quotes.
3. There's no need for the AJAX `url` function to be bound with `=>` anymore.
4. There's no need for any instance variables at all (unless of course there are things going on elsewhere).
5. I switched the arguments to `init` to supply the URL or data array in an object so that you can say:

   ```
   SelectTwo.init(el, 'pancakes', url: '...')
   SelectTwo.init(el, 'pancakes', data: [ ... ])
   ```

   instead of the (IMO) more cumbersome:

   ```
   SelectTwo.init(el, 'pancakes', '...')
   SelectTwo.init(el, 'pancakes', undefined, [ ... ])
   ```

   I find that positional arguments get ugly if there are more than a couple, doubly so when there are optional arguments that suppress earlier non-optional arguments.